# How to resolve an integrity error when trying to log in. (Django)

Tags: python, django

when I try to log in i get an error that says

```
 duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(mrfrasha) already exists.
```

I really don't have any idea what this means at all. It seems weird. this seems like an error you would get it you were trying to create a username that was already in use but i merely trying to log in.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
Password: <input type="text" name="password" />
<input type = "submit" value = "Login"/>< br />

def login(request):
    if request.POST=='POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password =request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return render_to_response('profile.html')
            else:
                print "Your account has been disabled!"#come back to me
        else:
            sentence = "Your username and password were incorrect."# come back to me
            return render_to_response('login.html', {'sentence':sentence})
    else:
        return render_to_response('login.html')#come back to me
```

Comment: Are you sure the code that handles the login is simply logging in the user? It seems that it is trying to create another user with the same unique key as an existing user. Are you able to post the code which handles the login in your views.py file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem which i think is that you have override the django `login` function by declaring the function of same name which then becomes recursive when this statement will execute `login(request, user)`.

As your function takes only one parameter that is why `login(request, user)` this statement cause exceptions that `login() takes one argument and got two`.

Change your function name to some other e.g. my_login(request)

Hope this helps.
Thanks

**EDITED**

Your function should be like this.

```
def my_login(request):
    if  request.method=='POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password =request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return render_to_response('profile.html')
            else:
                print "Your account has been disabled!"#come back to me
        else:
            sentence = "Your username and password were incorrect."# come back to me
            return render_to_response('login.html', {'sentence':sentence})
    else:
        return render_to_response('login.html')#come back to me
```

Comment: @Jack and obviously you have to change function name in your urls.py file which will point the request to `my_login` function.

Comment: Thank you. However, I did end up needing both request and user once i changed the name. not sure exactly why that is but it does seem to be working

Comment: Oh yes.. you have to pass request to login() function. Don't worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure this will fix the problem but there seems to be a problem here:

```
if request.POST=='POST':
```

request.POST is dictionary and will never evaluate to True in that comparison.

Perhaps try changing that to:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

This should at least get you into the correct if/else section of code.

Comment: that changed the error message to the fact that login() takes one argument and got two. so i think it worked

Comment: nvm. it doesn't work I still get the same error messgae I deleted the request from login ()

Comment: No, you shouldn't delete the request. The documentation says it requires the request object See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login . What authentication backend are you using?

Comment: alright? so i should delete the other one? and this may sound incredibly stupid but I have no idea what that really includes. I don't think i have set one up yet